# Matrix of pointers in gdb

Tags: c++, gdb

In GDB, how do you print `*M[0][0]`, where `M` is a 2D array? (Suggest a solution other than writing code to print and then call it from gdb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int *array = (int *) malloc (len * sizeof (int));
```

you can print the contents of array with

```
p *array@len
```

or you can check the link for more tricks

http://wagiaalla.com/2011/01/20/gdb-tricks-printing-arrays/